# How to run exe file on other system?

Tags: java, compilation, exe

I had a built for XML parser , Its running fine on my Lappi as i had compiled the code on same one , but when am trying to run this .exe file on other laptop which didn't have netbean or which didn't had compiled the java file  it showing error "Main Class " not found.

Is there any way to run my java .exe file in other system too as a general software do ?

Comment: How did you generate the `exe`?

Comment: What .exe? Sounds like a JAR file to me.

Comment: hi , I mentioned earlier in comment to answer the way i generated .exe file .. Its not jar file  its exe only

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything else about the situation, assuming your using some sort of build script system (such as Inno, or something along those lines), the reason you're seeing this error is because when you run a program inside of a netbeans file it has a built in manifest file. When you deploy something like that to a different system, you'll need to have a properly formatted manifest file that defines what the main class is. Depending on how you are constructing the .exe file in the first place, this can take place in a number of different ways. I highly recommend looking up manifest file creation for whatever you are using.

**EDIT**

Assuming you are using Launch4j, the attribute you would need is:

```
 <jar destfile="${launch4j.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">

        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>

        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>

        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>

        </manifest>

    </jar>
```

More or less. Obviously replace your destfile with whatever it ends up being, etc. etc.

Comment: Its a java simple program which is consisting on JForm class from Netbeans , Now what is happening "I am creating a jar file by Building is with Netbeans "after that am launching its exe file with 4Launcher tool , if possible just mail me ur id at "manujindal2011@gmail.com" and i will mail u the build

Comment: I don't really have time to go through a whole build file at the moment, but I will update the answer with this example better formatted. In nearly (every single) application of building exe's out of java code, some version or iteration of the code snippet I'll post up is required to get rid of the error you mentioned.